# Elquent Relation Limit records

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to send API with certain number of records

```
$category->products
```

I tried to use `limit()` or `take()` but it fails 
so is there any smart solution than go to pivot and select it with limit ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy data to a new collection.

```
$collection =$category->products;
```

you can now send the number of times you want using take ().

for example;

```
$collection->take(5);
```

if your question is different please explain it more clearly.

Comment: I will be very happy if you valid my answer. Happy coding @user10076385

Comment: If i want to skip also how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution I was easy

```
$category->products()->limit(2)->get()->all()
```

that's all